# Relationship between Stirling numbers of the first kind and their absolute value (possible error)

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, stirling-numbers

I am struggling to understand something from my lecture notes. I will state some definitions and then post the excerpt that I can't make sense of.

**Definitions:**

Let $c(k, n)$ be the number of permutations of $\{ 1, \dots, k \}$ with exactly $n$ cycles. Let $c(0, 0) = 1$.

Let $s(k, n)$ be the Stirling numbers of the first kind.

**Excerpt:**

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

**Discussion:**

I think the proof that the $c(k, n)$ are the coefficients of the expansion of the rising factorial is fairly straightforward. Since $s(k, n)$ are the coefficients of the falling factorial, I think this implies that $c(k, n) = \lvert s(k, n) \rvert$ because the expansion of $x^{(k)}$ should be the same as $(x)_k$ except that all the minus signs become plus signs.

I don't understand the part about $c(k, n) = (-1)^{k + n} s(k, n)$. In the proof, I don't understand what kind of operation "replace $x$ with $-x$" is. I can reason something like  the following:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 0}^k c(k, n) x^n &= x(x + 1) \cdots (x + k - 1)\\
&= (-1)^k (-x)(-x - 1) \cdots (-x - k + 1) \text{ (pull } -1 \text{ from each of the  } k \text{ terms)}\\
&= (-1)^k (-x)_k \text{ (recognizing the falling factorial with } -x)\\
&= (-1)^k \sum_{n = 0}^k s(k, n) (-x)^n\\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^k (-1)^{k + n} s(k, n) x^n,
\end{align*}

which concludes the proof. Is that right?

I'm a bit concerned there is an error somewhere because if you look at Wikipedia you see the following:

> [image],

and I don't understand how to reconcile the presence of the minus sign in Wikipedia's version.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

‘Replace $x$ by $-x$’ just means substitute $-x$ for $x$ in the equation

$$\sum_{n=0}^kc(k,n)x^n=x^{(k)}\,.$$

When you do that, you get

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^kc(k,n)(-x)^n&=(-x)^{(k)}\\
&=(-x)(-x+1)\ldots(-x+k-1)\\
&=(-1)^kx(x-1)\ldots(x-k+1)\\
&=(-1)^k(x)_n\\
&=(-1)^k\sum_{n=0}^ks(k,n)x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^k(-1)^ks(k,n)x^n\,.
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\sum_{n=0}^kc(k,n)(-x)^n=\sum_{n=0}^k(-1)^nc(k,n)x^n\,,$$

so $(-1)^nc(k,n)=(-1)^ks(k,n)$ for $n=0,\ldots,k$, and therefore $c(k,n)=(-1)^{k-n}s(k,n)=(-1)^{n+k}s(k,n)$ for $n=0,\ldots,k$. Your computation also works.

There is no conflict with Wikipedia’s $s(n,k)=(-1)^{n-k}{n\brack k}$:

$$(-1)^{n-k}=(-1)^{k-n}=(-1)^{n+k}\,,$$

since $n-k$, $k-n$ and $n+k$ all have the same parity.